# How does FPC compare to mammalian rennet?

Tags: cheese-making

How does fermentation-produced chymosin (bio-chemically engineered rennet) compare to real mammalian rennet? Does it affect the flavor of the cheese?

Answer (score 3):

it’s also known as recombinant chymosin. Per [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chymosin):

> FPC contains the identical chymosin as the animal source, but produced in a more efficient way.

Since it’s essentially produced by the same genes, the molecular structures of both products should be identical, thus the results.